# How to add multiple items from listbox to the database on a single button click?

Tags: c#

I want to add two or more selected items simultaneously to the database from a `listbox` on a single submit button. I can add item one by one but not all at a time by a single click. Please help me.

I Put it in the 'for' loop but when the loop is executing for the second time it shows me the exception that "Input string is not in correct format"

Comment: Add at least a snipped code! What did you do till now?

Comment: what kind of requirement is this, is the user going to click one listitem and then you will move two items? please clarify.

Comment: The listbox showing two or more items. So if the user clicks three items and press submit button then all the three items should add in database table simultaneously with the same id. This is my requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using checked list box then you can put your code inside the for loop. this will add two or more data on a single button click

```
string checkedMonths = "";
    public void GetCheckedMonths()                                              //To get all checked Months
    {
        string c = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBoxMonths.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (checkedListBoxMonths.GetItemChecked(i))
            {
                c = (string)checkedListBoxMonths.Items[i].ToString();
                checkedMonths = checkedMonths +", "+ c;                         //TO add selected moths with , in between them
            }
        }
    }
```

modify the above code according to your need. Here I am inserting two or more values as a single string in a single cell of a column. modify as you want inside the for loop...

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion..I Put it in the 'for' loop but when the loop is executing for the second time it shows me the exception that "Input string is not in correct format"

Comment: Please show you code here which you applied in the for loop.
"Input string is not in correct format" exception refers to the point that when the "for" loop is executing second time, the data type will be changing from string to int or vice versa. so you may need to convert the data type of variable which is showing exception.

Comment: @Losh one more thing need to know that a null nvarchar value can't be converted into an int or float or any another data type. This is the most reason behind the "Input string is not in correct format" exception.
- remember to accept and vote up my answer if its any way helps you. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
using (var command = <your data provider command>)
{
    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    // preferably - parameterize your command
    command.Parameters.Add(....); 
    . . . . . . . .
    //
    foreach (var item in lst.SelectedItems)
    {
        var sql = "Insert into tbl (a,b,c) values (. . use your list values here OR parameter names. .)";
        command.CommandText = sql;
        // if parameterizing 
        command.Parameters[name/index].Value = (....); 
        // ---
        command.ExecuteNonquery();

    }
}
```

Optional - if ALL-OR-NOTHING needed - use transaction.

Frankly, my answer is as good as question